# php setcookie path and domain

Tags: php

I am having a problem with setting cookie with php. I am trying to set a cookie `(id)` from `www.example.com/login.php` and I want to use from every place on the website. for example I want to use it in:

```
www.example.com/main.php
www.example.com/users.php
www.example.com/login.php
```

this is my php code

```
$expire = time() + 31556926;
$cookie_id = $insert_userid;
setcookie ("id");
setcookie("id", $cookie_id, $expire, '/', 'www.example.com');
```

i do not have any subdomain. Also For the domain index in the setcookie function I am not sure which on to provide. `www.example.com or example.com`

Comment: You don't need to call [setcookie()](http://br.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.setcookie.php) twice, call it just once

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
www.example.com
```

If you had subdomains and wanted to allow them:

```
.example.com
```

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie) is pretty useful on this:

> Most browsers, by default, allow first-party cookies—a cookie with
>   domain to be the same or sub-domain of the requesting host. For
>   example, a user visiting www.example.com can have a cookie set with
>   domain www.example.com or .example.com, but not .com.